# Running SSH Server on Android phone while not rooted?

Tags: android, ssh

I am looking into making a tool for my phone. One of the things I need is the ability to SSH into the phone. I was looking into different methods and one method was to use Socat however that requires root access. Another method I was looking into is using JSch library however it only includes the client code.

After looking at a few other SSH sources for Android it says that it requires root. Is this the only way to run SSH Server is by root? As far as I know, getting root requires rooting your phone correct?

Also, I am trying to do this all programmatically. Even if it is using `ProcessBuilder` on other binaries to get this accomplished. I just want to built it all into my own apk.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that running ssh requires root, but only if you want to use the standard port `22` *(see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218578943) for background & discussion on the mutual exclusivity of DalvikVM processes & privileged ports <1024)*

If you don't need port `22` specifically, try [Apache Mina](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md)? In just a few lines of code you can set it to listen to any port >=1024 and embed it in your app, e.g.

```
var sshServer = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshServer.setPort(1025);
sshd.start();
```

There's a bit more to it, but that's the basics.

---

Also worth noting that if you're running LineageOS, it comes with a standard ssh server (`/system/bin/sshd`, see [this blog](https://binfalse.de/2018/09/06/native-ssh-server-on-linageos/)) that you can enable by escalating to root, then either patch the exploit or uninstall your rooting tool to revert to an unrooted device. `sshd` will still work.

Comment: Update: As of LineageOS 18->19, sshd is broken, fix has been submitted awaiting approval https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/3437